# How to remove the dtype, index and name while writing to a csv file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas

my code is like this:

```
raw_data={'Crest_height':[crest_day.Crest],
          'Date':[crest_day.Date], 
          'Flood_Response':[flood_response]}

Flood_data=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
Flood_data.to_csv(r'crest_day.csv', index=False)
```

I have this output in a crest_day.csv file:

```
   Crest_height Date    Flood_Response
   "4    10.82
   Name: Crest, dtype: float64" "4   2016-08-18
   Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]"   Major Flood
```

I want to have a clean output in csv file, not the dtypes, index etc, 
     crest_day has two columns (Crest and Date) in float while       flood_response is a string

both have been returned from a function

Comment: If I only write crest_day to csv file like this: crest_day.to_csv(r'crest_day.csv', index=False)...this gives a clean output in csv file with only values, but in that case how to include flood_response(series type) in the crest_day.csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this block of code:

```
Flood_data=pd.DataFrame({
            'Crest_height' : list(crest_day.Crest),
            'Date':list(crest_day.Date),
            'Flood_Response':list(flood_response)
    })
Flood_data.to_csv('crest_day.csv', index=False)
```

Hope it helps.